# Word boundaries standard

Tags: standards, iso, word-count

Some time ago I found an ISO-standard(I think) which described boundaries to use in order to determine a word in a text based on different languages.

Is this something that I have made up in my dreams? Or can you help me find it? I've tried google but I didnt find anything.

Thanks,
BJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for. Sorry, no ISO-standard but an Unicode Standard Annex:

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-25.html